# json_decode decodes large numeric string as integer

Tags: php, json, integer

I have something like the following code:

```
<?php
$str = "76017060710034014696970658200876993546";
if(json_decode($str) !== null && json_decode($str) !== false){
  var_dump(json_decode($str));
}
?>
```

This results as followed:

```
int(9223372036854775807)
```

Ofcourse, this is no json string, and I expected json_decode to return either null or false, as described in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-returnvalues):

> Return Values
>
> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
>   true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
>   respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the
>   encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

How is this possible? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an option JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING, btw a string is a valid json. Try following:

```
var_dump(json_decode($str, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

Comment: I get this error: 
<strong>Fatal error:</strong> json_decode() [<a href='3function.json-decode3'>function.json-decode3</a>]: option JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING not implemented in <strong>/path/to/file</strong> on line <strong>125</strong>

How can I install this option? I use PHP Version => 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

Comment: It should be available for php v5.2 and above, I have phpv5.4.31  [See Jason decode manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Yes I know, so my configuration is not OK? Is there a way to install this option manually?

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to install only this option to you current php. I would recommend uninstall this version and installing the latest version, if I remember correctly you can do that using apt-get in ubuntu (I work on windows).